# How to replace indices values in a cell with the column value in a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, knn

I have a dataset with unique IDs and few attributes. I executed the k-d tree in Python to get the indices of each id for three nearest neighbors as shown in the following figure:
[image]

The "Index" in the above figure is the default indices that comes with a Pandas dataframe. I want the output in the format as shown in the figure below:
[image]

This can be easily accomplished in an excel using vlookup but how to do this in Python?

Comment: `index` is column?

Comment: no "index" is not a column. It is the default indices in a pandas dataframe. I just added it here for illustration purposes.

Comment: And all values in columns have to be replaced?

Comment: yes for neighbor1, neighbor2 and neighbor3 columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) by `Serie`s:

```
df = df.replace(df['id'])
#or convert to dict (first solution)
#df = df.replace(df['id'].to_dict())
print (df)
   id neighborl neighbor2 neighbor3
0  u1        u1        u4        u3
1  u2        u2        u3        u2
2  u3        u3        u1        u2
3  u4        u4        u1        u2
```

Another solution:

```
cols = ['neighbor1', 'neighbor2', 'neighbor3']
df[cols] = df[cols].applymap(df['id'].to_dict().get)
print (df)
   id neighbor1 neighbor2 neighbor3
0  u1        u1        u4        u3
1  u2        u2        u3        u2
2  u3        u3        u1        u2
3  u4        u4        u1        u2
```

If want more dynamic solution:

```
#select columns starting by neighbor
cols = df.filter(regex='^neighbor').columns
print (cols)
Index(['neighbor1', 'neighbor2', 'neighbor3'], dtype='object')

df[cols] = df[cols].replace(df['id'])
print (df)
   id neighbor1 neighbor2 neighbor3
0  u1        u1        u4        u3
1  u2        u2        u3        u2
2  u3        u3        u1        u2
3  u4        u4        u1        u2
```

---

```
#create mask by columns names starting by neighbor
mask = df.columns.str.startswith('neighbor')
print (mask)
[False  True  True  True]

df.loc[:, mask] = df.loc[:, mask].replace(df['id'])
print (df)
   id neighbor1 neighbor2 neighbor3
0  u1        u1        u4        u3
1  u2        u2        u3        u2
2  u3        u3        u1        u2
3  u4        u4        u1        u2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
In [289]: cols = ['neighbor1', 'neighbor2', 'neighbor3']

In [290]: df[cols].replace(df.set_index('index')['id'].to_dict())
Out[290]:
  neighbor1 neighbor2 neighbor3
0        u1        u4        u3
1        u2        u3        u2
2        u3        u1        u2
3        u4        u1        u2

In [291]: df[cols] = df[cols].replace(df.set_index('index')['id'].to_dict())

In [292]: df
Out[292]:
   index  id neighbor1 neighbor2 neighbor3
0      0  u1        u1        u4        u3
1      1  u2        u2        u3        u2
2      2  u3        u3        u1        u2
3      3  u4        u4        u1        u2
```

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
print df.replace(df['id'].to_dict())
```

Input:

```
       id  neighbor1  neighbor2  neighbor3
index                                     
0      u1          0          3          2
1      u2          1          2          1
2      u3          2          0          1
3      u4          3          0          1
```

Output:

```
       id neighbor1 neighbor2 neighbor3
index                                  
0      u1        u1        u4        u3
1      u2        u2        u3        u2
2      u3        u3        u1        u2
3      u4        u4        u1        u2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['u1', 0, 3, 2], ['u2', 1, 2, 1], ['u3', 2, 0, 1], ['u4', 3, 0, 1]], columns=['id', 'n1', 'n2', 'n3'])
print df
   id  n1  n2  n3
0  u1  0   3   2 
1  u2  1   2   1 
2  u3  2   0   1 
3  u4  3   0   1 

print df.assign(n1=df.n1.map(df.id),
                n2=df.n2.map(df.id),
                n3=df.n3.map(df.id))    

   id  n1  n2  n3
0  u1  u1  u4  u3
1  u2  u2  u3  u2
2  u3  u3  u1  u2
3  u4  u4  u1  u2
```